# How to treat Dry-Mouth (side-effect of medication)?

Tags: medications, side-effects, home-remedies, dry-mouth, saliva

Dr. prescribed medication that he noted had a **common side-effect of dry-mouth.**

Sure enough, it's a common side-effect!! Even though I **drink water** like a fish, my mouth was still like the Sahara. I had bought "**Biotene Moisturizing Mouth Spray**" as preparation, and I used it, and it gave me relief for like 5 minutes, but then my mouth quickly transformed into the Sahara desert again. So then I spent a lot of time **sucking on hard-candies**, but I don't think my Dentist would be too happy about me sucking on hard-candies, especially for long periods of time as I try to sleep.

**Basically, how is DRY-MOUTH treated (other than the ways I listed above -- drinking lots of water, mouth spray, hard candies) if one doesn't  wish to switch medication?**

Comment: @Those who have voted to "close" this question -- I've edited it. And I do believe this is on-topic as dry-mouth impacts my ability to sleep & speak & can lead to a plethora of oral hygienic issues. This is certainly health/medical related. If you don't believe so, would you kindly tell me why you voted that way so I may address it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your annoyance with dry-mouth. It can cause a whole host of issues so I certainly can commiserate, especially when it comes to trying to sleep with a dry-mouth!

Well, it seems like you have done a lot of your own research since you knew to invest in and experiment with Biotene Mouthspray, but just in case... here are some other treatment options (besides drinking water, gum-chewing, sucking on candy, staying hydrated, etc):

- decongestants can make your symptoms worse apparently (not sure why) so if you can, avoid them.
- if you can, try to breathe more with your nose and less with your mouth (it seems counterintuitive if the cause of your mouth-breathing is congestion, but decongestants make mouths drier??) maybe try nasal strips
- add moisture to the air (perhaps via a humidifier)
- limit your caffiene intake -- it can actually make it drier. Who knew?!

Here's more info: http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/dry-mouth/expert-answers/dry-mouth/faq-20058424

But the best recommendation I have and that I'm excited about because I just discovered it after talking to my dentist and oral-hygienist -- is try something that **stimulates saliva**. For instance, I've been using **XyliMelts**, and they have been working wonderfully for me. I can sleep much better because of them! You can find more products on their website here: https://www.oracoat.com/